# How to know if the firebase and Admob link is operational?

Tags: firebase, admob, firebase-admob

I have linked my AdMob application to a Firebase project to take advantage of the benefits of this combination.
But my old code (which worked when I only had AdMob) didn't work anymore, I had a lot of syntax errors ...
I saw on the Firebase website that I had to include the 'Google-Mobile-Ads-SDK' pod. But in the tutorial videos it was the 'Firebase/AdMob' pod.
But by including the 'Google-Mobile-Ads-SDK' directly, everything worked as before.
So I wanted to know if the link between AdMob and Firebase Analytics was still operational or if I had just implemented AdMob as before when I wasn't using Firebase.
Hence my question: how to check that the link is done?

Thank you for your attention

PS : I still include the 'Firebase' pod, I just remplace the 'Firebase/AdMob' by the 'Google-Mobile-Ads-SDK'. I would also like to understand what the 'Firebase/AdMob' pod is for if we can include 'Google-Mobile-Ads-SDK' directly and have the link made.

Comment: check your firebase events console to view automatically generated admob events. reference - https://support.google.com/admob/answer/9755157?hl=en

Comment: thank you, indeed they are present